# Honda Dirt Bike cr70r not accelerating well

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle

This is an older bike that sat still for over 10 years. Replaced the carb, fuel lines and valve. I have tried tuning the carb to solve the issue. Bike runs fine idle and rides ok slowly (in 1, 2 and 3) but once we rev the engine it does not speed. Sound like the engine is struggling, was expecting a higher pitch sound.
Appreciate tips for a beginner....

Comment: Assuming youve replaced carb with oem equivalent: Have you checked: air filter; spark plug, exhaust is clear and ignition timing is correct? Does it have good compression? Valve clearances?

Comment: What does "*Sound like the engine is struggling, was expecting a higher pitch sound*" mean? Please clarify.

Comment: The air filter is new as well as the plug. The plug seems fine. Did not check the exhaust (how do I do that, just check for obstacles?) Not sure how to check compression, plenty of air comes out when I rev the engine. Also not sure how to check ignition timing. New at this. The bike starts fine, runs idle very well. It accelerates ok in 1st but then flattens out (speed does not increase, feels like I have to changes gears). In 2nd and 3rd the bike seems normal. but in 1st I have enough power to start driving at 50%It sounds lean in idle but rich and clogging when trying to go full speed in 1.